# Get list of my Telegram channels I'm currently a member

Tags: ubuntu, telegram, desktop-application

Is there a way to get a list of channels I'm a member of in Telegram (preferably Telegram Desktop)?
I may be able to come up with a solution using JS in the browser or even Selenium, but isn't there a more ergonomic approach that would work in Telegram Desktop (like an API)?

If it matters I'm running Telegram as a snap application on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a list of channels I'm a member of in Telegram ***(preferably Telegram Desktop)***?

Well, the official [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not have an option to get members of a channel. So using [Telegrams MTPROTO](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) to make your own client that will do this is the only legit way of retreiving this data.

As said, you could scrape the [Telegram Web Version](https://web.telegram.org/k/), but thats most likely to change some time soon which you'll need to edit your scraper.

[Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) seems like a valid/stable solution, continue reading for a custom example script

---

> Is there a way to get a list of **channels** I'm a member of in Telegram (preferably Telegram Desktop)?

If you just want to know what channels you're member of, you can use the `dialog.entity` to check if the current one is of type `Channel`

1. Use [`client.iter_dialogs()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs) to loop over each channel
2. Use `isinstance` to check if it's a `Channel`

   - This will make sure we don't log for types like:

     - `User` (chats)
     - `ChatForbidden` (Chats your kicked out off)

---

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import  Channel

import asyncio

async def main():

    async with TelegramClient('anon', '2234242', 'e40gte4t63636423424325a57') as client:

        # For each dialog
        async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs(limit = None):

            # If this is a Channel
            if isinstance(dialog.entity, ( Channel )):

                # Log
                dialogType = type(dialog.entity)
                print(f'{dialog.title:<42}\t{dialog.id}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Will output something like

```
channel_1           <channel_id>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) library that allows you to act programmatically from your account.

Here is minimized code from [Quick Start](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/quick-start.html) that allows to print all of your chats. There you can do whatever filtering or processing you need.
Even if you'll want to write something there.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import Channel


# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # Getting information about yourself
    me = await client.get_me()

    # "me" is a user object. You can pretty-print
    # any Telegram object with the "stringify" method:
    print(me.stringify())

    # You can print all the dialogs/conversations that you are part of:
    print("You are subscribed to following channels:")
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs(limit=None):
        if isinstance(dialog.entity, Channel):
            print('Channel ', dialog.name, 'has ID', dialog.id)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: This will just log every dialog you have, not limited to Channels.

Comment: @0stone0 it is easy to add any customizations when you have access to that. Updated answer with that.